# how to get the output of a command via rpyc?

Tags: python, rpyc

I need to run a command via rpyc and get the result of this command.

But whenever I run the command, it is printed on the remote server and can not bring the result.

What I am doing is the following:

```
import os, sys
import rpyc

conn = rpyc.classic.connect('server_remote')
a = conn.modules.os.system( "ls -lh")

print a
```

The output of my command is 0 for any command I run.

```
python get_output.py
0
```

Comment: this has got nothing to do with rpyc. you'd get the same behavior if you just run `system( "ls -lh")` locally (accept that stdout would be local to the process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use os.popen or subprocess.checked_output instead of system. System just returns the exit code, while the output is printed to your stdout (i.e. you don't get hold of it  programmatically)